# Appropriate ways to dismiss street vendors?

Tags: saying-no, public-issues, netherlands

In the Netherlands, it seems to be quite common lately to hire some students, put them on a busy main street or outside a supermarket, and have them target every passerby by asking 'Can I ask you something?'.

These people are always selling stuff I am not interested in (newspaper subscriptions, services that deliver food to your house every week) or they are trying you to sign up to become a permanent donor for a charity (in which I am also not interested).

My approach so far has always been:

- Do not make eye contact
- Continue walking without changing pace/trajectory (unless one jumps in front of me, then I swerve)
- Reply 'You just did' (gentle, joking tone of voice, smile on my face) if they ask me 'Can I ask you something'

Usually, this either generates a weird look if somebody doesn't get the joke, or a chuckle if they do. Even bystanders seem to like it. But yesterday, a lady came to me saying that what I was doing was very impolite.

Are there any better ways to dismiss street vendors?

Comment: I agree "you just did" could be construed as offensive and passive-aggressive, at least here in the UK. This is mainly because the butt of the joke is the vendor themselves.

Comment: And... reprimanding random people in the street about not listening to street vendors is *not* rude? I wonder where she came from...

Comment: @Hashim Honestly, people would have to have a really thin skin to construe that as offensive. It's a harmless joke.

Comment: @Rob - Unfortunately, many, many of those people exist, and they need to be considered for the purpose of questions like this. Hell, half the purpose of sites like this is to account for those people.

Comment: @Rob But actually, in this context, I kinda disagree. Being British, passive-aggressiveness is probably the most common form of rudeness there is, so it can definitely be offensive. For me personally, I'd only find it offensive if it's clear to me that the person intends it to be so. Usually you can tell the difference between someone being a dick and being light-hearted.

Comment: Amsterdam? Which city?

Comment: @Blaszard: Sometimes at the entrance of the village supermarket, sometimes in the main street of any city (Apeldoorn or Zwolle for example).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Put yourself in the shoes of the person who is making a very small salary trying to get you to sign up for things. They need to get a certain number of "yes" over the course of a day. They know they will get a lot of "no". The ideal no is fast and is not rude or hurtful. A slow no may be of some value if it causes other people to gather round and one of them may be a yes. A rude no just makes the job miserable and soul destroying.

What is a rude no?

- get out of my way
- can't you get a real job instead of blocking the sidewalk bothering people?
- [to other passersby] these things are all scams, stay away!
- any kind of joke making fun of their script, costume etc

You think that "you just did" is funny, but it really says "I'm smarter than you, so I am mocking you and frustrating your purpose at the same time!" I agree with the lady who told you it was rude. There's no need for it, you just went out of your way to make a joke at the expense of someone who has an unpleasant job.

If you're not interested, don't be interested. Keep on going and let them do their job. Your first two bullets are perfect.

Comment: The important bit here is a fast no, so you don't cost them money. Spot on.

Comment: @Kate Gregory: Thank you for your answer! This really is the most helpful answer for me, since it actually explains why making the joke was considered rude. And with that knowledge, I can avoid being rude the next time.

Comment: Personally I just use the good old 'smile politely while shaking your head no'. Saves me the energy of speaking and the street vendor gets a clear signal.

Comment: I'd just also like to add that even if the joke isn't hurting, it's a common joke that those vendors probably hear several times a day, which can become super annoying really quickly, so it's still a kindness to not say them (like cashiers hearing "Then it must be free !" if an item doesn't scan; harmless, but annoying with repetition).

Comment: Old post, but I'm wondering why you didn't mention "No, not interested" as an explicit example in your answer? (like SQB answer and many others did). I would assume that's one of the most standard expression of "no" that is still reasonable for denying street vendors, and that it hasn't been mentioned in the question by OP. So I assume you must have some apprehension in using that phrase, and if that's the case, I'm curious why.

Comment: @justhalf the examples in my answer are all rude no's that should be avoided. I don't think saying "no, not interested" is rude or should be avoided. I have no apprehension about using that phrase if you feel the need to say something to the person.

Comment: @KateGregory ah, I guess because the original question (title and last Q in body) is "Are there any better ways to dismiss street vendors?" I was expecting suggestions of what to say. It seems like you focus more on the middle part of the Q, about whether it's rude? But OP accepted this, so perhaps that's the implicit actual Q by OP.

Answer (score 31):

> "No thanks, I'm not interested."

That's the boring, but correct way to react. They're busy selling something, so knowing you're so thoroughly uninterested in their product that they're definitely not going to get a sale out of you lets them move on to another target quickly.

You're not wasting each other's time. This is the polite thing to do.

---

However, *they* are bothering *you*, trying to sell their product. So a small harmless joke like

> "You just did. Thank you."

...is perfectly all right. Especially if you remain friendly and your tone of voice makes clear that you're not interested.

As long as you're not mean to them and don't waste their time, it's all right.

Comment: [Some might consider](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/a/3224/3296) a joke at someone else's expense to be mean.

Comment: Well, the joke seems to imply that it's a stupid question, and presumably that they're stupid for asking it, so I'd say yes, it is at their expense (although that's not to say everyone would be offended by it).

Comment: @NotThatGuy The vendor is fully aware that they are wasting the time of hundreds of people just for their personal gain. If they ignore clear body language and disinterest of someone who is in a hurry - and accept that person may be late because of their personal greed, a harmless joke at their expense is not even beginning to be rude. If they talk to me when I'm clearly not interested, they are bad at their job - because they should target potential customers instead of annoying uninterested people

Comment: Wish I could upvote Falco's comment twice. So many people lose sight that the vendor is being egregiously rude in wasting the time of hundreds of people just for their personal gain. Worrying about a mild joke in this context is more than anything implicity encouraging the vendor to continue annoying people.

Comment: @NotThatGuy .... so what? I'd argue wasting my time is mean.

Answer (score 15):

If they approach you, you can always just say:

> I'm not interested, thank you.

That could still be considered a little rude (although for the Netherlands, it's probably fine), but less rude than simply ignoring them (or making a joke at their expense).

A middle ground between this and ignoring them would be looking at them and shaking your head (in an "I'm not interested"-kind of way, not in an "I'm judging you so hard right now" way).

Both of these can be somewhat awkward if the person is not actually trying to sell you something but is rather just trying to e.g. get directions.

If you want to be even less rude, you'd need to actually hear them out (but who has time for that...).

---

I personally tend to opt for just ignoring them, but I also don't really care if they think I'm rude.

Comment: You're really that important that you don't have time to hear a person out?

Comment: @Hashim what benefit is gained for either party if you're not interested in the product? You waste your time listening and theirs trying to sell to someone who has no interest in buying.

Comment: @Catija You can only know there's a product by hearing someone out. A person could just be in need of directions or some help. It takes less than 20 seconds to find out. Of course this assumes you're aware someone is a street vendor, but the impression I got from this answer was that he'd ignore anyone that approached him on the street.

Comment: @Hashim You clearly don't have the same vendors we do. If you get caught they will trap you uncomfortably for the better part of five minutes.

Comment: I would like to add, that it is really obvious these people are vendors: sponsored jackets and banners.

Answer (score 8):

In Japan nodding/bowing is really common, so it may not be as applicable in your country, but I just nod my head in their direction showing that I acknowledge them as a human being and recognize/respect their efforts, but continue walking as I am not interested.
This shows that you aren't judging them or being condescending, but rather  you really are not interested in being sold to, or are in a hurry.

Comment: This would be really confusing in the Netherlands. - Nodding implies "yes" here and people will think you are inviting them for a follow up question. Shake your head instead. (Or just say "no thanks".)

Answer (score 3):

> No, I'm not interested, thank you

This is good enough. It may be good to know that street vendors in The Netherlands have to stop trying to sell you a product once you have made it clear that you want them to stop doing that.

In case you find the above a little too rude, you can always let them say their thing first and then tell them you're not interested. You're not the only person that doesn't like street vendors and that's why they often try to keep their first message short and to the point, so it usually shouldn't take more than five seconds for them to finsih their first message.

However as someone from The Netherlands myself I wouldn't consider directly saying that you're not interested rude.

Answer (score 3):

Trying the classic "Sorry but I'm not interested" should work in most cases, but if the vendor still persists, try this:

> Look, I don't want to waste your time by letting you tell me everything about your product and then walking away without buying it because I'm not interested (busy/in a hurry). So, thank you but no, thank you.

It would be a good idea to keep your smile natural and tone gentle while conveying this message and most of the times, people will understand.

Comment: Compared to, "May I ask you a question?" it's a long speech. "No." doesn't waste their time or yours. "Not interested." wastes very little time and conveys to some more strongly that you're not going to change your position. In the time your answer takes, they could've pestered five other people.

Answer (score 2):

Please be sure that this type of street vendors has a good salary indeed. It is reputed to be one of the best earning activities for time & money pinched students these days.

I try to keep it silent always.

Once one of them is inside my trajectory, first I spy if I'm targeted. If I am, I seek eye contact and shake my head to indicate I'm not interested. And I smile very nicely.

99% of the time this works, no problem.

In the rare case my preferences are ignored they receive my ***dagger stare*** and possibly the word ***'NO'*** *(emphasis intended)*.

By this time I'm seriously annoyed and any further attempt to reach out to me comes full stop.
Hopefully this will work for you too :-)

Answer (score 2):

If they are trying to me sign up for a charity I reply;

> Thank you, I am already a supporter of your organization.

They seem pleased and do not engage me any further.

Comment: Simple, yet effective. A very elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

"No thanks" and walk on. Polite and doesn't waste your time or theirs

This is even appropriate *no matter what their specific question is*. It doesn't have to address the wording of their question. e.g. Even if it's not an offer, or if they are making a request to you.

e.g.

Q: "Can I ask you a question?" - A: "No Thanks", walk on.

or

Q: "Have you got a minute?" - A: "No thanks", walk on.

This might seem like an odd answer, but there is a reason they phrase the question in such a way - it's a sort of psychological sales trick or tactic to get you to stop so they can talk to you, they are trying to play off your politeness.

They know that if they phrase it as if they are asking a favour of you (e.g. by saying "Can I ask you a question?" or "Do you have a minute?") and you just say "No", you will feel rude or uncomfortable, therefore you'll be reluctant to do that.

So If you just say "No thanks", no matter what they said, they'll get the message, and you'll get to keep your feeling of politeness.

Comment: This is my default answer even to less polite queries or demands. In some cases their reaction shows slight confusion, but I consider that a plus. In any case, it gets the point across.

Answer (score 0):

"Thank you but no.  Have a nice day!" should work.

I always tell such people that I have a policy of not buying from door-to-door people, street vendors, or whoever (I really do have this personal practice), so I am going to do them a favor and let them go so they can find someone who will.

If they are proselytizing for a religion other than my own, though, I tell them that I won't talk to them but I will take their literature if they take mine (I keep a small supply of information about my faith, some about how it conflicts with various faiths that are likely to be proselytizing, handy at all times and places -- in my purse, my car, right next to my front door, etc.).  After they keep trying to talk to me and I keep repeating this, after a few times they get the drift and stop trying.  :)